# MDS why IE reloads all SOD scripts on page change, chrome does not

Tags: sharepoint-online, internet-explorer, chrome, mds

I was testing my MDS script loading and noticed that for the most part chrome loads SOD script only once while IE requests all of them every time. Is there a fix for IE since we advise our users to use IE when using SharePoint.

[image]

In both cases I am browsing the same page library folder after 2 page jumps so most of my SOD scripts can load.